# applyConstraints(), getCapabilities() not working on Electron for Windows

Tags: electron, webrtc

Unable to get or apply any constraints using **getCapabilities()**,  **applyConstraints()** on a camera app built on *Electron (v2.0.4)* for *Windows*. getCapabilities() returns an empty object.

However, I am able to get and apply constraints on Ubuntu 16.04, and Raspbian with the same camera, same version of Electron. It also works fine when I run the index.html directly on chrome on Windows.

Is it not supported yet on Electron for Windows or am I doing missing something?

To run the application, put the following files in a directory, run **npm install** and **npm start** in that directory.

**package.json**

```
    {
      "name": "webrtc",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "description": "WebRTC",
      "main": "main.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "latest"
      }
    }
```

**main.js**

```
    "use strict";

    const electron = require("electron");
    const app = electron.app;
    const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

    const path = require("path");
    const url = require("url");

    let mainWindow;

    function createWindow()
    {
      mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1920, height: 1080});
      mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true
      }));

      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

      mainWindow.on("closed", function(){
        mainWindow = null
      });
    }

    app.on("ready", createWindow);

    app.on("window-all-closed", function(){
      app.quit();
    });

    app.on("activate", function(){
      if(mainWindow == null)
      {
        createWindow()
      }
    });
```

**getCamera.js**:

```
    "use strict";

    const video = document.getElementById("video");
    var constraints = window.constraints = {
      audio: false,
      video: {
        width: {ideal: 1280},
        height: {ideal: 720},
      },
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(videoSetup).catch(errorHandling);

    function videoSetup(stream)
    {
      const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      console.log("Device: " + track.label);
      window.stream = stream;
      video.srcObject = stream;
      setTimeout(function(){
        // track.applyConstraints({video: {width: 1920, height: 1080}});
        var capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
        console.log("Capabilities: " + JSON.stringify(capabilities));
      }, 2000);
    }

    function errorHandling(error)
    {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    }
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Camera Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div>
        <video id="video" playsinline autoplay width=100%></video>
      </div>
    </body>

    <script src="getCamera.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Output of **getCapabilities()** on Electron Windows: Capabilities: {}

Output of **getCapabilities()** on Chrome Windows/ Ubuntu/ Raspbian:

Capabilities: {"aspectRatio":{"max":2304,"min":0.0006510416666666666},"brightness":{},"colorTemperature":{},"contrast":{},"deviceId":"b054cbcea100ef88ffbe463a2caee133a5fd10b11915d0e2c5a230fdbf4776b9","exposureCompensation":{},"exposureMode":["continuous","manual"],"facingMode":[],"frameRate":{"max":60.000240325927734,"min":1},"height":{"max":1536,"min":1},"saturation":{},"sharpness":{},"whiteBalanceMode":["continuous","manual"],"width":{"max":2304,"min":1},"zoom":{}}

Answer (score 2):

electron 2.0.4 is based on Chrome 61 (check navigator.userAgent) which didn't have a meaningful implementation on getCapabilities whih shipped in Chrome 66. applyConstraints shipped in Chrome 63 as far as i can remember, even though the release notes don't mention it.

Comment: That was my first thought too but I was confused when I tried it on Ubuntu 16.04. It works fine there, I am able to get and apply all the constraints there.

navigator.userAgent returns the same versions for webrtc, Chrome, electron on both Windows and Ubuntu.